# Haskell iterate over a list

Tags: list, haskell, nested, loops

I know you suppose to think differently in Haskell, but can someone give me a quick answer on how to iterate over a list or nested list and print out a character based on the value of the list element.

```
list1 = [[1 0 0][0 1 0][0 0 1]]
```

By iterate through this nested list, it should print out x for 0 and y for 1

```
yxx
xyx
xxy
```

Thanks

Comment: More generally, when moving from an imperative language to a functional language, you probably want to stop think about "iterating over a list" and think more in terms of functions like `map` and `filter`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, I think you mean:

```
list1 :: [[Int]]
list1 = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

As for what you want:

```
valueOf :: Int -> Char
valueOf 0 = 'x'
valueOf 1 = 'y'
valueOf _ = 'z'

listValues :: [[Int]] -> [String]
listValues = map (map valueOf)

printValues :: [[Int]] -> IO ()
printValues = putStrLn . unlines . listValues
```

And then in ghci:

```
*Main> printValues list1 
yxx
xyx
xxy
```

Comment: I dont get how this can work? http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/map_f.html here it says map need a function and a list as an parameter, but in this example (map valueOf) only gets a function which returns char as an parameter                                                           Also does get the function valueOf no Parameter, but it needs an Int.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
fun :: [[Int]] -> [String]
fun = (map . map) (\x -> if x == 0 then 'x' else 'y')
```

If you really need printing of result:

```
printSomeFancyList :: [[Int]] -> IO ()
printSomeFancyList = putStrLn . unlines . fun
```

Answer (score 2):

define f by something like

```
f x = if x == 0 then 'x' else 'y'
```

then

```
map (map f) [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

is what you want or if you want it fancier:

```
map' = map.map
map' f [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The solutions using `map` are the preferred Haskell style. But while you're learning, you may find explicit recursion easier to follow. Like so:

```
charSub :: Int -> Char
charSub 0 = 'x'
charSub 1 = 'y'
charSub x = error "Non-binary value!"

listSub :: [Int] -> String
listSub [] = []
listSub (x:xs) = (charSub x) : (listSub xs)

nestedSub :: [[Int]] -> String
nestedSub [] = []
nestedSub (y:ys) = (listSub y) ++ "\n" ++ (nestedSub ys)
```

`map` does pretty much the same thing--it applies a function to each element in a list. But it may be easier to see what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in arbitrary nested lists, then you can write something like this (an arbitrary nested list is essentially a tree):

```
data Nested a = Leaf a | Nest [Nested a] deriving Show

traverse :: Nested Integer -> Nested Char
traverse (Leaf x) = Leaf (valueOf x)
traverse (Nest xs) = Nest (map traverse xs)

valueOf :: Integer -> Char
valueOf 0 = 'x'
valueOf 1 = 'y'
valueOf _ = 'z'
```

With that you can do:

```
Main> let nl = Nest [Leaf 1, Leaf 0, Nest [Leaf 0, Leaf 0, Leaf 1, Nest [Leaf 1, Leaf 1, Leaf 0]], Nest [Leaf 1, Leaf 1]]
Main> traverse nl
Nest [Leaf 'y',Leaf 'x',Nest [Leaf 'x',Leaf 'x',Leaf 'y',Nest [Leaf 'y',Leaf 'y',Leaf 'x']],Nest [Leaf 'y',Leaf 'y']]
```

The function `traverse` takes an arbitrary nested list of `Integer`s and returns a corresponding nested list of `Char`s according to the `valueOf` rule

Comment: You might have some fun trying to define a true arbitrarily nested list: i.e. the sum of the types `[a], [[a]], [[[a]]], [[[[a]]]], ...`  Disallows eg. `[[0,1],2,[[3],4]]`, which a tree allows.

Answer (score 1):

```
iterateList = foldl1 (>>).concat.intersperse [putStrLn ""].(map.map) (\c ->  putStr $ if (c==0) then "X" else "Y")
```

Comment: You will need import Data.List (intersperse,foldl1)

Comment: You can replace `concat.intersperse` with `intercalate` and should replace `foldl1 (>>)` with `foldr (>>) (return ())` so it doesn't crash. `sequence_` is even nicer.

Comment: Further, you can use `mapM_` to bring it to `mapM_.((>> putStrLn "").).mapM_ $ \c -> ...`. :)

Answer (score -1):

The solutions

```
cambiar = putStr.unlines.(map (map f)) where f x = if x == 0 then 'x' else 'y'
```

Comment: cambiar [[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]  ==>  
yxx             
yyx                                                                  yyy